# Label geojson polygons with Leaflet .bindtooltip

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm having difficulty getting labels to appear in polygons using Leaflet's .bindTooltip(). Do I have to use L.Polygon() to make it work? I've tried a few online examples to no avail

Here's the code I'm presently trying:

```
var parcels = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/parcels.geojson", {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {
            color: "red",
            weight: 2,
            fill: false,
            opacity: 1,
            clickable: false
        };
    }
});
parcels.bindTooltip(function (layer) {
    return string(layer.feature.properties.BCT);
});
```

and later:

```
map = L.map("map", {
    zoom: 13,
    center: [41.74737922562798, -70.0688695],
    layers: [watercolor, brewster, parcels, points, highlight],
    zoomControl: false,
    attributionControl: false
});
```

geojson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":     "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 244, "PID": "24-90",     "BCT": "BCT167", "OWNER_TYPE": "A", "LOCNO": 0.000000, "LOCEXT": null, "STREET": "Abbey Road" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -70.122083808134178, 41.741357529630378 ], [ -70.121829265447474, 41.74058589548401 ], [ -70.121802814040251, 41.740505709250201 ], [ -70.121800033448579, 41.740492712460984 ], [ -70.121800054122147, 41.740479550571351 ], [ -70.121802876026265, 41.740466559455449 ], [ -70.121808424682214, 41.740454070484319 ], [ -70.121816560938697, 41.740442403440611 ], [ -70.12182707515619, 41.740431857443312 ], [ -70.121839698257986, 41.740422700276177 ], [ -70.121854108980713, 41.74041516667446 ], [ -70.121869938857245, 41.74040945028117 ], [ -70.121984916556499,...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Leaflet 1.0+, try with:

```
var parcels = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/parcels.geojson", {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {
            color: "red",
            weight: 2,
            fill: false,
            opacity: 1,
            clickable: false
        };
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.BCT);
    }
});
```

Comment: I was getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`, appending `.toString()` to `feature.properties.param` solved it. Maybe because my property was numeric and was present in the data sans quotes.

Comment: @nikhilvj You're right... If the property is numeric then it has to be converted to String.

Comment: I don't remember needing the `.toString()` in earlier leaflet, seems to be a new thing. Worth filing a bug?

Comment: **OLD** version. Not need AJAX, please add modern `L.geoJSON(data, {etc})`  simple code.